# Debugging the Code

Tags: c, debugging

Hello Guys I am starting the voyage of debugging the code, and ran the following commands  as per the book just for some analysis for the source code below

```
 // hello_world-1.c
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
      printf("hello world\n");

      return 0;
```

`gcc -Wall -Wextra -c hello_world-1.c // What is wall and  wextra here` ?

```
  $ size hello_world-1 hello_world-1.o 
   text   data   bss    dec   hex   filename
    916    256     4   1176   498   hello_world-1
     48      0     0     48    30   hello_world-1.o

$ objdump -h hello_world-1.o 

   hello_world-1.o:     file format elf32-i386

   Sections:
   Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
     0 .text         00000023  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**2
                     CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, RELOC, READONLY, CODE
     1 .data         00000000  00000000  00000000  00000058  2**2
                     CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
     2 .bss          00000000  00000000  00000000  00000058  2**2
                     ALLOC
     3 .rodata       0000000d  00000000  00000000  00000058  2**0
                     CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
     4 .note.GNU-stack 00000000  00000000  00000000  00000065  2**0
                     CONTENTS, READONLY
     5 .comment      0000001b  00000000  00000000  00000065  2**0
                     CONTENTS, READONLY
         48      0     0     48    30   hello_world-1.o
```

I have some question here

1) There are no global variables in hello_world-1.c. Then why the size reports that the data and bss segments have zero length for the object file but non zero for the executable?

2) Why size and objdump report different sizes for the text segment?

Comment: yhou seem to have a mis-impression.  1) there is no executable generated. 2) size is showing certain statistics for the source file and for the object file.  An object file is not executable.  to get an executable file, another step needs to be performed.  "gcc hello_world-1.o -o hello_world"

Comment: You need to compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g hello-world.c -o hello-world.bin`

Comment: It seems that executable **was** generated. At least `size hello_world-1` returns some info.

Comment: hello_world-1.c **does have** global variable - it's "hello world" of type `const char *` The rest is due to C standard library. See my comment at the end of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object file consists of .text (i.e. binary CPU instructions), .rodata (read-only data - "hello world"\10\0 - 13 bytes total) and .comment (additional linking information).
Executable file consists of the same minus .comment plus standard library stuff plus import dynamic library data, if any.
Standard library adds at least startup code, which makes executable bigger. So your difference is: **executable .text = .object text + startup code + stdlibrary code (if static linking)**.

Answer (score 1):

regarding your question:

"gcc -Wall -Wextra -c hello_world-1.c // What is wall and wextra here ?"

(note capitalization counts)

-Wall tell the compiler to enable most warnings

-Wextra tell the compiler to enable even more warnings

-c tells the compiler to only compile, not link.

because no '-o objfilename.o' parameter was included,
the compiler will ouput an object file with the same name as the input file, with a '.o' extension.

suggest always include the '-o objfilename.o' parameter explicitly

suggest performing some online googling for such things, wherein you would have found pages similar to :

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_3.html

Comment: Thanks for the support But can you please explain the other two questions also ?

Answer (score 0):

here is a copy of the man page for 'size'

SIZE(1)                      GNU Development Tools                     SIZE(1)

NAME
       size - list section sizes and total size.

SYNOPSIS
       size [-A|-B|--format=compatibility]
            [--help]
            [-d|-o|-x|--radix=number]
            [--common]
            [-t|--totals]
            [--target=bfdname] [-V|--version]
            [objfile...]

DESCRIPTION
       The GNU size utility lists the section sizes---and the total size---for
       each of the object or archive files objfile in its argument list.  By
       default, one line of output is generated for each object file or each
       module in an archive.

```
   objfile... are the object files to be examined.  If none are specified,
   the file "a.out" will be used.
```

OPTIONS
       The command line options have the following meanings:

```
   -A
   -B
   --format=compatibility
       Using one of these options, you can choose whether the output from
       GNU size resembles output from System V size (using -A, or
       --format=sysv), or Berkeley size (using -B, or --format=berkeley).
       The default is the one-line format similar to Berkeley's.

       Here is an example of the Berkeley (default) format of output from
       size:

               $ size --format=Berkeley ranlib size
               text    data    bss     dec     hex     filename
               294880  81920   11592   388392  5ed28   ranlib
               294880  81920   11888   388688  5ee50   size

       This is the same data, but displayed closer to System V
       conventions:

               $ size --format=SysV ranlib size
               ranlib  :
               section         size         addr
               .text         294880         8192
               .data          81920       303104
               .bss           11592       385024
               Total         388392


               size  :
               section         size         addr
               .text         294880         8192
               .data          81920       303104
               .bss           11888       385024
               Total         388688

   --help
       Show a summary of acceptable arguments and options.

   -d
   -o
   -x
   --radix=number
       Using one of these options, you can control whether the size of
       each section is given in decimal (-d, or --radix=10); octal (-o, or
       --radix=8); or hexadecimal (-x, or --radix=16).  In --radix=number,
       only the three values (8, 10, 16) are supported.  The total size is
       always given in two radices; decimal and hexadecimal for -d or -x
       output, or octal and hexadecimal if you're using -o.

   --common
       Print total size of common symbols in each file.  When using
       Berkeley format these are included in the bss size.

   -t
   --totals
       Show totals of all objects listed (Berkeley format listing mode
       only).

   --target=bfdname
       Specify that the object-code format for objfile is bfdname.  This
       option may not be necessary; size can automatically recognize many
       formats.

   -V
   --version
       Display the version number of size.

   @file
       Read command-line options from file.  The options read are inserted
       in place of the original @file option.  If file does not exist, or
       cannot be read, then the option will be treated literally, and not
       removed.

       Options in file are separated by whitespace.  A whitespace
       character may be included in an option by surrounding the entire
       option in either single or double quotes.  Any character (including
       a backslash) may be included by prefixing the character to be
       included with a backslash.  The file may itself contain additional
       @file options; any such options will be processed recursively.
```

SEE ALSO
       ar(1), objdump(1), readelf(1), and the Info entries for binutils.

COPYRIGHT
       Copyright (c) 1991-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

```
   Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this document
   under the terms of the GNU Free Documentation License, Version 1.3 or
   any later version published by the Free Software Foundation; with no
   Invariant Sections, with no Front-Cover Texts, and with no Back-Cover
   Texts.  A copy of the license is included in the section entitled "GNU
   Free Documentation License".
```

binutils-2.23.91                  2013-11-18                           SIZE(1)